# Why am I getting 'module not installed' error?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to use other components but then out of no where but `react` and `react-native` are underlined and it's throwing me an error causing me not use components.

The error is:

```
Module is not installed


Checks whether the module in the "require()" call or import statement exists, whether it is is listed in package.json dependencies, and whether it is locally installed.
Suggests installing the module and/or including it into package.json.
For require() calls, works only in files in the scope of "Node.js Core" JavaScript library.
```

I tried to run `npm install module --save` but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: What IDE are you using and did you try to remove node_modules and npm install again?

Comment: Can you give more of the error--what module is it saying isn't installed?

Comment: Please copy code as text and not an image. Also, what is `Module`? The command you listed will install [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module) which is not a React Native component. What are you attempting to use here?

Comment: @MichaelCheng I'm trying to use this right here https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: @Raymond I'm using Webstorm.  No I haven't tried that.

Comment: In that case, you are using the wrong install command for that package. Per the GitHub README, you should be using `npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save` to install it. Then you need to import it with `import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'`.